# What is the best way to escape MySQL data to output to JSON?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, perl, escaping

I need to **output data for javascript** (array of array) from MySQL
I am using this code, which works fine except that REPLACE function
I need to **modify all the text** that goes into JS array's inverted comas ' -- ' **as per JS format**. And **can be used for all the fields in 1 go**.
I need a replace function that will escape all data, i.e. `\ -> \\` ; `' -> \'` ; `newline -> \n`

```
$sth=$dbh->prepare('
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        "\n[\'",
        CONCAT_WS("\',\'", d6id, REPLACE(d6name,"\'","\\\\\'"), d6date),
        "\']"
    )
    FROM d6lastdate
');
$sth->execute();($json)=$sth->fetchrow_array();
```

### Output

```
['0000000001','CA\'T','2011-09-26'],
['0000000002','CWE','2011-09-23'],
['0000000003','MAT','0000-00-00'],
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just json_encode the bare result of the query?

Comment: Wow, are you really trying to json_encode from SQL?

Comment: I was just trying to see if we can generate JSON from SQL directly, as half of my `SELECT` statements needs to output JSON.. I didn't try DBIx::JSON though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is probably to do this outside of MySQL.

```
$data = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref();
$json = encode_json($data);
```

`encode_json` is provided by [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3a%3aXS).

Comment: @Atul Gupta, Fixed so it's just Perl now.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sth=$dbh->prepare('
    SELECT d6id, d6name,d6date
    FROM d6lastdate
');
$sth->execute();
$json = encode_json($sth->fetchrow_arrayref());
```

`encode_json` is provided by [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3a%3aXS), among others.

Comment: @CanSpice, I'm sure he meant [`encode_json`](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asearch.cpan.org+encode_json) and not [`json_encode`](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asearch.cpan.org+json_encode). Both responses originally used `fetchrow_array` when they should have been using `fetchrow_arrayref` too. Better now?

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP is not always an option (what if you want a stored procedure to insert a row in a table, where one or more fields are json formatted strings?).

Your initial approach is almost good... if you except that the result is not valid JSON:

- You need to use double quotes (") instead of simple quotes (') as string delimiter
- Don't forget to escape the backslash (\) too
- If your strings include special characters, be sure that they are encoded in UTF-8
- The last comma (,) will cause issue and need to be removed

Eric

Edit: You also need to escape carriage returns, tabs and a few other characters. Have a look at string definition on this page: http://www.json.org . 
 You may validate your resulting json string with http://jsonlint.com .

Comment: adding one more field to table to store json-formatted string is nice idea, that can be done in long run as currently my database isn't that stable and its structure is being modified daily.

Comment: `$sth=$dbh->prepare('
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  json_string  )
    FROM d6lastdate
');
$sth->execute();($json)=$sth->fetchrow_array();`

Answer (score 0):

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;

$sth=$dbh->prepare('
    SELECT d6tag, d6id, d6name, d6cat, d6date
    FROM d6lastdate
    ORDER BY d6date
');$sth->execute();

$json=Dumper($sth->fetchall_arrayref);
```